# how to make a void returning a datatable?

Tags: c#, multithreading, datatable, void

I want to use multithreading for the first time as I understood, there is 2 laws to respect:
-Threads can be used only with void's
-One cannot use Threads to change something in a windows form(unless you use delegates).

So I code my macro by respect to this rule, here is my code :

```
public void exec_RT(string tickername, bool isSubIndex)
{
    DataTable RT_dt = Price_dt(tickrname, isSubIndex);
    Infragistics.Win.UltraWinChart.UltraChart toplot = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinChart.UltraChart();
    toplot = forms.Real_timeAlpha;
    configgraph(RT_dt, toplot);
}
```

My problem is that the function  Price_dt return a datatable :

```
public DataTable Price_dt(string tickername, bool isSubIndex)
{
    DoMyThing();
    return real_time;
}
```

So my question is how can I make a void return a datatable ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know much about multi threading but you can achieve this by using out parameter.

Comment: `Threads can be used only with void's` - Not true. Take a look at the TPL for this.

Comment: Try to use TPL `Task` and `Task<T>`classes

Comment: To be quite honest, those aren't the 2 laws to respect ;-)

Comment: Have you tried using callbacks? Check this article for inspiration http://blog.bitlinkit.com/asynchronous-callback-threading-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

you can use class members for storing the datatable.

```
public DataTable Price_dt(string tickername, bool isSubIndex)
{
    DoMyThing();
    this.setDT(real_time);
}
```

i'm pretty sure you have to (/should) use an invoke for setting the table (therefore the function).

you can reffer the "stored" table in every other part of your class.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass the `DataTable` to your method and work in that table. Since `DataTable` is a reference type all your modification are on the original object to witch both variables reference (your original variable and the one from inside Price_dt).

Your method would go from this

```
public DataTable Price_dt(string tickername, bool isSubIndex)
{
    DoMyThing();
    return real_time;
}
```

to this

```
public void Price_dt(DataTable yourDataTable, string tickername, bool isSubIndex)
{
    //modify yourDataTable here
    DoMyThing();
}
```

Comment: you still can't return `real_time` you have to `yourDataTable = real_time` (i hope that `real_time` is the table ... it's not clear (for me)

Comment: @Alex of course I simply add forgot to remove the `return` statement. the datatable will be modified outside of the method without having to return it.

Comment: I just tried it the idea is nice but it does not work , the Datatable yourDataTable come back empty in exec_RT

Comment: @francopshenri how have you tryed? I use this kind of behavior at several place in my code and it work properly

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a global variable to store your DataTable in

```
public void exec_RT(string tickername, bool isSubIndex)
    {
        DataTable RT_dt = Price_dt(tickrname, isSubIndex);
        Infragistics.Win.UltraWinChart.UltraChart toplot = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinChart.UltraChart();
        toplot = forms.Real_timeAlpha;
        //global variable of the type DataTable
        globalTable = RT_dt;
        configgraph(RT_dt, toplot);
    }
```

And use globalTable for whatever you may need later on.